# Deploying jenkins into an existing kubernetes cluster fails dues to "Insufficient oath scopes"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-kubernetes-engine

So am trying to deploy Jenkins into my existing k8s cluster, but then am getting this notification (insufficient OAuth scopes). what scope am I missing on my service account?
[image: storage admin and project owner scopes are already assigned to the given service account am using for this project]

Answer (score 0):

This is a GCP issue.

Make sure that the user you are using to launch the service has **Owner** or **Compute Admin** privileges on your GCP project.

[image: gcp]

Answer (score 0):

By default Node pool are created with the following scopes which does not include the [right scope](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes):

> `"nodePools": [
>         {
>           "name": "default-pool",
>           "config": {
>             "oauthScopes": [
>               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
>               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
>               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
>               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
>               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
>               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
>               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
>             ],`

**To fix the error:**

If this is a GKE test Cluster, just recreate it with the right scope. You can create a new [node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/node-pools) with the required [scopes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes) and then [migrate](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool) your workloads over to the new node pool. [image: right scope]

If you are using gcloud, add this scope:

`--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`

If you decide to recreate the Node Pool, remember to drain and delete the old Node Pool afterwards. I think the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750479/insufficient-oauth-scope-when-trying-to-deploy-jenkins-click-to-deploy-on-an-exi) will be helpful as it related to your case.

Comment: After Jenkins is deployed, you can run the following command from the Cluster to obtain the password to complete the setup: `$ kubectl -ndefault exec   $(kubectl -ndefault get pod -oname | sed -n /\\/jenkins-1-jenkins-deployment/s.pods\\?/..p)   cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword`